# visual line mode is ended by inner block motion

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions, object-motions

When I do `Vi{y` to select inside a `{` block and yank it, it doesn't paste how I expect.

I noticed that after `V` (which puts me into VISUAL-LINE mode), the `i{` object takes me into `VISUAL` mode.

Here's a gif:

[image]

I wanted the paste `p` to put the text *underneath* where my cursor was, as if I had yanked some text while in VISUAL-LINE mode.

If I start visual mode with shift-V, I want object motions like `i{` to keep me inside of that mode.

Comment: @klaus "this won't happen by default" — I don't think I changed my defaults

Answer (score 1):

```
i}                          *v_i}* *i}* *i{*
i{                          *v_iB* *v_i{* *iB*
iB          "inner Block", select [count] Blocks, from "[count] [{"
            to the matching '}', excluding the '{' and '}' (see
            |[{|).
            When used in Visual mode it is made characterwise.
```

You can use `getregtype()` to check register type.

`Vi{` will change visual mode to `v`,  you can hit `V` again to return to `V`.

As long as lines of `{` and `}` don't belong to lines of `i}`, `yi}` will result in `V` type register, you should use `yi}` in your case.

Comment: you're right `yi{` works, but why doesn't `Vi{` work the same way. I find this frustrating

Comment: `i{` in Visual mode switch current Visual mode to characterwise.

Comment: @theonlygusti, `Vi{` doesn't work cause there is no such thing as `Vi{`.

Comment: @klaus is there a way to make it a thing?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>See `:h intro` for more details</sup>

Vim has seven BASIC modes:

- Normal mode
- Visual mode
- Select mode
- Insert mode
- Command-line mode
- Cmdline mode
- Ex mode
- Terminal mode

There are six ADDITIONAL modes.  These are variants of the BASIC modes:

- Operator-pending mode
- Replace mode
- Virtual Replace mode
- Insert Normal mode
- Insert Visual mode
- Insert Select mode

As you can see, there is no mode called `visual-line-mode` that you talked about in your question. There are just three kinds of `visual-mode`, none of which are modes themselves:

- Characterwise visual (see `:h characterwise-visual)
- Linewise visual (see `:h linewise-visual)
- Blockwise visual (see `:h blockwise-visual)

Read `:h visual` for more details.

If you look through `:h text-object`, you will see that the text objects you're talking about, i.e. `i{` are not acceptable for `linewise-visual` style of visual mode. Because, text-objects are supposed to work with visual-mode and after an operator, see `:h text-objects`. That's why Vim intelligently changes the type of visual mode you were in, because it makes sense. But of course, you're in complete control with just one more keystroke.

**Suggestion:** Use `vi{` to visually select the content inside the curly braces and press `V` to start visual line mode over the already selected lines. This is the default way.